# Winforms Label on top of gif

Tags: c#, winforms, label, gif, picturebox

I want to place a Label on top of a gif inside a PictureBox in winforms.
The problem ist that the label has a white background. I want it to be transparent.

My Code is as follows:

```
this.pictureBox = new PictureBox();
this.pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("my_background.gif");
this.pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

this.label = new Label();
this.label.Text = "Hallo";
this.label.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
this.label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
           
this.Controls.Add(this.label);
this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox);
```

My problem is that the Label has a white Background even though the background is set to transparent. The solution for other having a similar problem was setting the parent of the label to the picture Box like this:

```
this.label.parent = this.pictureBox;
```

But that didn't solve the problem for me. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Remove this: `this.Controls.Add(this.label);` and replace it with `pictureBox.Controls.Add(label):` (or set the Parent). Note that the location of the Label is now related to the new Parent (the PictureBox). Refesh the Label and set `Autosize = true`, if required

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint.

It worked fine when putting only a view controls in front of the gif. When adding to many it got very buggy and only some rectangular parts of the gif would update.

I solved the problem by splitting my gif into single images and displaying them in the OnPaint Event of the form

```
this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.Paint_Background);
```

The Paint Method looked like this.

```
private void Paint_Background(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics background_graphics = e.Graphics;
    Graphics graphicsObj;
    graphicsObj = this.CreateGraphics();

    int image_num = ((int)((DateTime.Now - start_time).TotalMilliseconds) / gif_speed) % num_images;
    Image background= Image.FromFile("Filename_"+image_num+".jpg");
    background_graphics.DrawImage(background, 0, 0, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
    background.Dispose();
}
```

All of my Controls where added directly to the view and not the imagebox anymore, as the imagebox was removed entirely.

Maybe this can help someone else too